# how to display 2 images one after the another in sequence in same window using OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am using OpenCV in python and the aim of the code is to display one image after another in the same window without destroying it. For eg. i1.jpg is displayed and then in the same window left arrow is displayed after a pause of 5s. 
In my case, i1.jpg is displayed and then the window is destroyed and then i2.jpg is displayed in another window.

Here is the code for the same -

```
t_screen_time = 5000

import numpy
import cv2

left_arrow = "left_arrow.jpg"
right_arrow = "right_arrow.jpg"

img = cv2.imread(left_arrow)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(t_screen_time)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

img = cv2.imread(right_arrow)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(t_screen_time)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: See if you can work out which call is destroying the window between displaying the two images...

Answer (score 0):

The argument in `cv2.waitKey()` is the time to wait for a keypress and not exactly the time the image is displayed for.

`cv::imshow()` or `cv2.imshow()` was not designed to be a complete GUI. It was designed to let you quickly debug and display images/videos.

You can achieve what you need using some form of `sleep()` in a thread or so. But this is harder to do in python. You could also just edit your code to

```
t_screen_time = 5000

import numpy 
import cv2

left_arrow = r"first/image" 
right_arrow = r"second/image"

img = cv2.imread(left_arrow) 
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(t_screen_time) 

img = cv2.imread(right_arrow) 
cv2.imshow('image',img) 
cv2.waitKey(t_screen_time) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

by removing the `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` before displaying the second image. I've tested this code and it works, but if you're looking for more GUI functionality, use something like Qt.

Comment: this will display the next image in new window, not in the same window